# How to programatically open a file with a certain application and change the extension

Tags: python

I have hundreds of .exr files that I need to convert to .png -- however, each file has to be opened with an application to ensure it has the proper exposure, etc. (which are conveniently the default settings on the app), then saved to a folder. Thus for every file, I have to

1. Drag the file from Finder into a QT4Image window to open it with QT4Image. The default exposure and gamma on QT4Image are appropriate, so no changes need to be made there. It requires no visual confirmation, it just needs to be opened on QT4Image.
2. Click File -> Save As.
3. Copy and paste the file name, and add ".png" to the end of it, so that it's saved as "[same file name].png". The file name is the exact same as it was, except now ends in .png instead of .exr Ex. file32.exr would become file32.png
4. Put it in the right folder (all the .png files are going in the same folder).

It's a trivial task but very time consuming, and I am wondering if people have any advice how I would go about coding this instead of doing it manually?

Comment: "then saved as "[same file name].png"." This part is also unclear. How do the new names relates to the old names? Just changing the extension and directory or more?

Comment: This sounds like a wonderful job for a small bash script. Is the application for converting the files available from a command line? What does `<path to your application>/QT4Image --help` say?

Comment: Dup link probably looks a bit sketchy, but I'm 99% sure it's what you need - get Imagemagick, run mogrify as described, see if that doesn't set you right...